# How many times is the process command repeated in the code snippet? Why?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, timing

This snippet of code is not related to a specific language and is actually about the effect of two four loops on the final result.

```
For(int i=0;i<n-i;i++)
  for(int i=0;i<n-i;i++)
    process;
```

How many time is the "process" command repeated in the code?
Why?

Comment: That is not the syntax of any language I know and it uses the same iteration variable in both loops, though possibly not in conflict for local scoping. Depending on the language that could be allowed and have interesting effects, or be forbidden. This makes the question hard to answer. Please clarify.

Comment: This snippet of code is not related to a specific language and is actually about the effect of two four loops on the final result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume that

- `For` is a typo for `for`
- `process;` is actually an allowed syntax for a statement
- the inner `int i` creates a local variable which is not in conflict with the outer `i`
- all inner `i` refer to the same variable

Then the both loops will iterate until `2*i <= n`, i.e. n/2 times, give or take 1 for odd n.
Being nested and independent (see assumptions above) it will result in `process;` being executed `(n * n) / 4` times.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping all the assumptions intact according to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759330/3942262), we can generalize in little mathy version as following.

```
Number of times "process" command repeated = ceil(n/2) * ceil(n/2)
```

This result is irrespective of even or odd. Let me explain a little, when we try to solve the inequality as given in the loop condition ***i < n - i***, it gives ***i < n / 2***. If we put an even number in place of **n**, then both loop will run ***n/2*** times. For odd number **(say 11)**, if we closely see the inner loop then it will run for all integers from 0 including 5 (similarly for outer loop) and total number of times it runs is 6. On the other hand if that number was 10 then the loop couldn't have run for 5 as per the loop condition and total number of times it runs is 5. Now come to our condition ***i < n / 2***, put 11 and 10, it will result 5.5 and 5 respectively. Hence in general number times loop run is ***ceil(n/2)***.

Comment: While this looks correct and useful, you may provide some additional explanation.